# Facebook linter (aka "object debugger") complains about my URL, but everything seems ok

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

My site has some URLs that are rewritten by .htaccess... i.e. this:

```
 http://lastminuteislandvacation.com/villa/15/st-john-rental-villa-angelica
```

is invisibly re-written to:

```
      http://lastminuteislandvacation.com/villa.php?id=15
```

However, when I plug all this in the Facebook Linter, I get this error message:

> "Errors That Must Be Fixed: There was an error in fetching the object at URL
>   'http://lastminuteislandvacation.com/villa/15/st-john-rental-villa-angelica',
>   or one of the the URLs specified via a redirect or the 'og:url'
>   property including one of
>   http://www.lastminuteislandvacation.com/villa/15/st-john-rental-villa-angelica."

What does that mean, and is it a problem I need to worry about or is it just the Linter complaining?

FWIW as far as I can tell, all my open graph tags on the page are fine, and there's nothing unusual about rewriting a URL via .htaccess. My shares on Facebook seem to look and work correctly, with all the right metadata, image, etc. In other words: there's no problem that I can see, but that whole "Errors That Must Be Fixed" part has me mildly concerned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I try your urls in the debugger the results I get are just fine, there are no errors what so ever.

[For the short (.php) version](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http://lastminuteislandvacation.com/villa.php?id=15) I get this:

```
Fetched URL:    http://lastminuteislandvacation.com/villa.php?id=15
Canonical URL:  http://lastminuteislandvacation.com/villa/15/st-john-rental-villa-angelica
URL for Likes:  http://lastminuteislandvacation.com/villa.php?id=15
```

And for the [longer one](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http://lastminuteislandvacation.com/villa/15/st-john-rental-villa-angelica) I get this:

```
Fetched URL:    http://lastminuteislandvacation.com/villa/15/st-john-rental-villa-angelica
Canonical URL:  http://lastminuteislandvacation.com/villa/15/st-john-rental-villa-angelica
```

In the *Scrape Information* section.

Also, at the bottom (*Urls* section) you can see that they both get the same [Graph API url](http://graph.facebook.com/10150665723373459)

Comment: Good old Facebook! The errors have mysteriously disappeared :-) Thank you... E

Comment: Facebook caches the scrapped data so that it won't have to issue a request per share/like/what not, my guess is that the errors you received were for a cached version, usually using the debugger overrides the cached version.

Comment: @NitzanTomer are you sure?  I'm sure Facebook caches the scraped data for use during likes/shares, but I've seen claims (although not on Facebook itself) that the way to get Facebook to discard its cached data and re-scan your URL is to use the linter.

Comment: That's exactly what I wrote: *usually using the debugger overrides the cached version*. The debugger is the linter.